# Getting value of an object by key in typescript

Tags: typescript, types

I need to create an object with keys of another object and infer the type from string, for example.

```
const result = rebuild(query, {
    name: 'string'
});

// query - { name: '123', dont_need: true }
// result - { name: '123' }
```

I made the function, but struggle with typing. I tried this approach:

```
type Type = 'string' | 'number';
type Config = Record<string, Type>;

interface ConfigType {
    string: string;
    number: number;
}

type RebuiltResult<T extends Config> = {
    [key in keyof T]: ConfigType[T[keyof T]]
}
```

But the return type says that `name` is `string | number`, which makes sense because I just use general `keyof T` to get the type. I know it's possible to get the specific type, but I don't know how.

More examples:

```
const query = {
   name: 'Ivan',
   money: 3000,
   age: 20
}

const ivan = rebuild(query, {
   name: 'string',
   money: 'number'
})

// type -  { name?: string; money?: number }
// value - { name: 'Ivan', money: 3000 }
```

```
const ivan = rebuild(query, {
   name: 'string',
   money: 'string'
})

// type  - { name?: string; money?: string }
// value - { name: 'Ivan' }
// no money, since it's a number
```

Comment: COuld you please provide more information about expected result with more examples

Comment: @captain-yossarian I provided more examples. To remind you, I already have a function, but struggle with types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const query = {
  name: 'Ivan',
  money: 3000,
  age: 20
}

type Primitives = string | number | symbol;
type Mappings<T> = T extends string ? 'string' : T extends number ? 'number' : never;

type ConvertQuery<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: Mappings<T[P]>
}

type ConvertReturn<Query, Props> = {
  [P in keyof Props]?: P extends keyof Query ? Query[P] : never

}

declare function rebuild<Query, Props extends Partial<ConvertQuery<Query>>>(query: Query, props: Props): ConvertReturn<Query, Props>;

const ivan = rebuild(query, {
  name: 'string',
  money: 'number'
})

ivan.money // string | undefined
ivan.name // stirng | undefined


// type -  { name?: string; money?: number }
// value - { name: 'Ivan', money: 3000 }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAjgVwKYCcCeMC8MDeAoGGMAQwFskAuGAcgEkA3YsagGgJlPCTSoGYAGQW0LEA5pRgAmfngC%20ePFDQAHJDAAKKAJaktULfSQQsMaNrCiYAHyIJSAI1TXTaByAA2AbkUq1AWWJlZS0LCAAeABUAPhMImCQADygkMAATYzMQywB%20GkyLahgqOMTktOMwO0cUGFzqSodUQqowJEMUbx9VGABhcHaoAEVkdEiY7HxCAG11GBCYAGtuEAAzGAiAXSoAoKzwiJmNqLkFJW6%20sAGAJSQoBBQwMOHUNBYNFBBlCHHcdhm5sCLZZrTSfCAbbJUWalFLpIFoVYwZ7oWpIkZoQ5FIhtVAKeR4VJIYDuYgoNQrBBgYD6cAwMn2BBadypJ7ot6gr7xJKw4zqUn6YjuMIXAbItCsl5RKUACkQLyoYreyg%20XyhKogAEoqCLUFAbncHhL0Oz1VFOqBILADEwTPTGczZWzfoQSOQqNR8qJWOxOK0eDQGtVqHINQprWAAHS%207gwAD0sdMUHMlhslMJKxCSFSeHDEddanjia0DxTMDTSAzrWzCkLZzUAFpCDgiGQkJDE8nPBwuGh24GnPJC4x3MgYI3m-n3QwmKxu36%20IJ%20DBZEA)

I did not write implementation, only types.
Let me know if it works for you